# How do you copy a table from MySqlServer_A to MySqlServer_B?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5, bulk

I have a daily task that collects data from 3 MySql Servers and then pushes that aggregate data back out to each of the servers deleting the previous days data. All servers are MySql. I would like to put this into a stored proc.

I have been searching for a way to connect from one MySql Server to another, run a query, next server - rinse and repeat. Besides not finding any examples of a stored procedure that connects to another MySql server, my immediate impression is that this is not really acceptable, nor intended.

I can select into an outfile which creates a CSV. Is there any way to force an Xml document instead? I don't want to have to read into a datatable just to get Xml. Of course, Xml won't work with the Bulkload method, will it?

What are my realistic options? One concern about selecting into an outfile is the use of weird characters: ``` ' ,  \ \\ & @ `` / // ``` etc...how will those characters affect the Bulkload process?

Comment: would federated tables help here?

Comment: possibly ... I was looking at the federated table and it looks like it would; however, we *gasp* do not have a DBA and it requires modifications to production servers that no one wants to make (that is if I am understanding the way a server instance must be started to enable federated tables) ...

Comment: Alas, now we hit a troubled patch ... no dba, but needing the advice and usefulness of one. Yay for having this site. Cringing for what happens when things go "kabloom"

Comment: @jcolebrand: I cringe everyday ... yay for this site and consultants!!! Would a single federated table on the primary server work for pushing data out to 2 servers? I see the samples only ever connect to a single remote. Would I have to essentially have 2 federated tables?

Comment: I ... am not that strong on mysql. I would have to defer to some of the other users of this site. They'll be along shortly, I'm sure.  Now, were this MSSQL I would be all over it. I'm not a mod because I know all the platforms, just cos I don't mind being a good janitor ;)

Comment: @IAbstract Please run SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname \G on the master table, and the source tables. If the tabl structures is identical, please provide just the one. Update this question show we can see it, please.

Comment: @Rolando: I just covered this with my dev mgr and it is possible that I will have the dubious honor of this task as you have outlined it below. We're upgrading servers and MySql to the latest and greatest. So after we are done with that I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to shy away from the FEDERATED storage engine for three(3) reasons:

1. It only supports MyISAM
2. DDL performed on the source table requires manually changing the FEDERATED table design on external services.
3. Bulk operations against a FEDERATED table can become an instant mightmare !!!

What to do ???

One possibility is to use mysqldump and merge them

EXAMPLE
Assuming all tables have identical structures
Assuming all tables are not using auto_increment IDs
Assuming all tables are InnoDB

On the server that will combine the three tables, create four(4) import databases (one time operation):

```
CREATE DATABASE ImportDB1;
CREATE DATABASE ImportDB2;
CREATE DATABASE ImportDB3;
CREATE DATABASE ImportCombined;
```

Import Process Goes Something Like This

mysqldump the three(3) tables

```
mysqldump -hHOSTIP1 -Pportnumber1 -u... -p... dbname tbname > /root/ImportTable1.sql &
mysqldump -hHOSTIP2 -Pportnumber2 -u... -p... dbname tbname > /root/ImportTable2.sql &
mysqldump -hHOSTIP3 -Pportnumber3 -u... -p... dbname tbname > /root/ImportTable3.sql &
wait
```

Load the mysqldumps into the separate import databases in parallel:

```
mysql -hHOSTIP4 -u... -p... -A -DImportDB1 < /root/ImportTable1.sql &
mysql -hHOSTIP4 -u... -p... -A -DImportDB2 < /root/ImportTable2.sql &
mysql -hHOSTIP4 -u... -p... -A -DImportDB3 < /root/ImportTable3.sql &
wait
rm -f /root/ImportTable1.sql &
rm -f /root/ImportTable2.sql &
rm -f /root/ImportTable3.sql &
wait
```

Next, combine the data.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ImportCombined.tbname;
CREATE TABLE ImportCombined.tbname LIKE ImportDB1.tbname;
ALTER TABLE ImportCombined.tbname DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO ImportCombined.tbname SELECT * FROM ImportDB1.tbname;
INSERT INTO ImportCombined.tbname SELECT * FROM ImportDB2.tbname;
INSERT INTO ImportCombined.tbname SELECT * FROM ImportDB3.tbname;
ALTER TABLE ImportCombined.tbname ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE ImportCombined.tbname ENABLE KEYS;
```

Now, perform the task you already have in place against the ImportCombined.tbname table.

"You fill in these steps"

Then, when the table is ready to be exported, mysqldump it and copy 2 times:

```
mysqldump -hHOSTIP4 -Pportnumber4 -u... -p... ImportCombined tbname > /root/ExportTable1.sql
cp /root/ExportTable1.sql /root/ExportTable2.sql &
cp /root/ExportTable1.sql /root/ExportTable3.sql &
mysql -hHOSTIP1 -Pportnumber1 -u... -p... -A -Ddbname < /root/ExportTable1.sql &
mysql -hHOSTIP2 -Pportnumber2 -u... -p... -A -Ddbname < /root/ExportTable2.sql &
mysql -hHOSTIP3 -Pportnumber3 -u... -p... -A -Ddbname < /root/ExportTable3.sql &
wait
rm -f /root/ExportTable[123].sql &
```

As show from these steps, these things should be shell scripted and perhaps crontab'd.

---

Here is another maneuver: If the tables are MyISAM, you could copy the MyISAM tables (.frm, .MYD, and .MYI files for each table) in other folders (databases in the eyes of mysqld) instead of doing mysqldumps, and perform similar operations as mentioned before. Make sure no writes to the tables take place during the copy.

Comment: ... wow ... probably won't be doing this any time soon. As I told @jcolebrand, we don't have a DBA. I think I have managed to do what I need to with a console app. It appears, as in your example, that you can `mysqldump` a single table ... which we didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an ETL tool like http://www.pentaho.com/ for this?

Sounds ideal..

Comment: What's your relation with pentaho? ;) ~ Helps to spell out _why_ you think this is a good tool

Comment: Oh, its just an open-source ETL tool. You can also use Talend - also opensource.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/158761)